# Use TLS certificate from a domain owned, and use it at URL given by AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm building a **websockets application** that runs on:

- `NodeJS`

Environment with:

- `Nginx`.

Using library at `app.js`:

```
...
const https = require('https');
...
```

And the websockets at `app.js`:

```
...
const webSocket = require('ws');
...
```

It works if I use a self signed certificate and ***force the client not to authenticate server*** certificate with *CAs*...

**But there's a client application that *doesn't support self signed certificates*.**

So, I came across [here](http://blog.lookfar.com/blog/2017/05/18/how-to-add-ssl-to-a-single-instance-ebs-server-for-a-node-js-app/) and [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=89622)...

I'm thinking about issuing a certificate for a *subdomain of a domain I own*. And use the files to *run the websockets application at **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** environment*.

1. Is that idea possible?
2. Do I need to have a domain name for the beanstalk application?
3. Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot!

Kind regards,

Jon.

Comment: It is completely fine to answer the own question. But you must not answer this using an edit in the question itself, you instead should create a real answer using the _answer_ button.

Comment: Oh holy edits @t.niese , htanks a lot for the feedback, will do right away. Learning to StackOverflow on-the-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @t.niese for the  feedback. Thanks @Abhyudit for your proposal for out traffic to domain-server of my own.

Tried to setup *Route53*. But come to realize that I was trying to impersonate my domain using *elastic beanstalk* *AWS* provided resource `URL`. So it was not possible as the docs say.

Then, tried the management of certificates with *Amazon Certificate Manager*, by importing the information from a domain I truly own, setup URLs, wildcards, in order to call *elastic beanstalk* environment. And it did the trick. Just make sure to call the right *URL* with the right *port*.

Kind regards all! :D

Jon.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CNAME record in Route53 for the URL given by Elastic Beanstalk and then your domain will point to your Elastic Beanstalk application.

Refer to this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html

Comment: Hi @Abhyudit . Tried to setup Route53, but the issue with that method, is actually the issue I was trying to solve. Because I'm pointing traffic to _elastic beanstalk_, but like "impersonating" the domain I own. So, read that's not possible. Hence, a Security undoable thing. Opted for importing TLS certificates, and specified sub-domain wildcards and specific URLs for different services running. That way, I can call to _elastic beanstalk_ using my domain, and the *certificate-key* used at websocket server will prove to be genuine and secure. Thanks a lot for your time and attention!